# Parallel lines probability question

Tags: probability

I came up with this question so that I could better understand a bit of probability; I'm still kinda young so simplified answers would be very helpful :)

**Q:** Imagine that you have a 500km highway; each side has 5 lanes and has each lane has 2 cars; all of which have random starting positions **within the highway** so that they do not overlay each other. What is the probability that the cars would form 4 parellel lines?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I don't understand your question...how do cars form lines (parallel or otherwise)?  We already know that all $5$ lanes are occupied (right?) and don't those lanes form $5$ parallel lines?